# How to pass value of NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to AWS Lambda deployed with Serverless?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate, serverless

I am deploying a Node [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) with [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless). Due to the internal requirements of the institution in which this code will be run, I need to pass extra certificates. The only solution I've been able to find is to pass [NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) as a CLI argument. Using typical environmental variables (defined, for example, in [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)) does not work because by that point in Node the certificates have already been configured.

My extra certs are in `MyCerts.pem` in the project root, and the Lambda function I'm trying to run is called `function1`. Running the Lambda locally with `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./MyCerts.pem npx serverless invoke local -f function1 -l` works correctly. However, once I deploy to AWS using `npx serverless deploy -v`, I cannot find a way to properly include these additional certs, including by invoking from the CLI using `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./MyCerts.pem npx serverless invoke -f function1 -l`.

I've tried everything I can think of and am at a loss. Can someone help?

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: any luck with a solution?

Comment: Also discovered adding os.environ["AWS_CA_BUNDLE"] = "..pem file.." works for my solution, which is also an internal requirement for my inst.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should definitely be possible in AWS Lambda.
There is an example on dev.to [1] which is similar to your use case.
However, they are using .NET Core and the AWS SAM, but it should be easy to adapt the solution to serverless and Node.js.

Basically, you need two steps:

1. Create a Lambda layer which holds your additional certificate file [2][3]
2. Add the environment variable *NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS* to your serverless.yml and point the path at the file you uploaded in your Lambda layer [4]

#### References

[1] https://dev.to/leading-edje/aws-lambda-layer-for-private-certificates-465j
[2] https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-layers
[3] https://www.serverless.com/blog/publish-aws-lambda-layers-serverless-framework
[4] https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too and taking Martin Loper's inputs, I had set environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` prefixed with `/var/task/` and then the path inside my lambda code base where the cert is actually located. e.g. it would like like `/var/task/certs/myCustomCA.pem` if I had a folder `certs` in my lambda with `myCustomCA.pem`.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me. I am using webpack to bundle the lambda code into a single `.js` file with outputs headed to something like a `dist/lambda` folder. Using the [copy plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy the needed CA cert into the same output folder, I can zip the whole thing up and tell Lambda that `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` live at `/var/task/myCert.pem`. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` works in Lambda. I tried setting it as an environment variable to a dummy file that doesn't exist. It did **not** generate a warning as stated by the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) so I assume it was ignored.

> A message will be emitted (once) with process.emitWarning() if the file is missing or malformed, but any errors are otherwise ignored.

I assume it's because of this warning:

> This environment variable is ignored when node runs as setuid root or has Linux file capabilities set.

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63903761/492773) confirming it doesn't work.

I was able to get Node.js to pay attention to `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` by starting another `node` process from the Lambda function. That second process gave me the warning I was looking for:

```
Warning: Ignoring extra certs from `hello.pem`, load failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
```

I am sure there are a lot of downsides for starting a secondary process to handle the request (concurrency would be my main concern), but it's a workaround you can try.

```
const ca_env = Object.assign({NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS: "hello.pem"}, process.env);;
require("child_process").execSync('node -e "console.log(\'hello\')"', {env: ca_env});
```

Comment: That are interesting notes! Since I did not test my solution yet, I took the time and created a small lab: EC2 instance with self-signed certificate and public IP; I added the self-signed to the Lambda bundle and added the env variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = /var/task/rootCA.crt. My https client was able to make the call after adding the env variable. In my case the environment variable was picked up correctly by node.js.

I guess the warning in your case was not printed since Lambda might (possibly) start logging the node.js output at a later point and NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS is read very early.

Comment: I also checked the status of the running process for "/var/lang/bin/node" using the proc filesystem from a bash script: "cat /proc/$PPID/status". The node process for the Lambda is running as a non-privileged user - without the suid bit set. Furthermore, I did not receive any Linux file capabilities when querying for them using "getcap /var/lang/bin/node". I guess the "secure_getenv" security measure in node.js which causes trouble and is mentioned in the docs - as you pointed out correctly - should not be an issue for AWS Lambda.

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder why so many people are having issues with it, if it just works.

Comment: Maybe they set the variable to the wrong path an do not get an error log. Maybe the bahaviour is not consistent across different node runtimes? Idk... if someone who got it working is reading this, please reply here.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the same issue and resolved this by uploading the cert in the project folder, then the node should be able to use the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`

Lambda layer storages the cert in the `/opt` folder which i think the node module don't have the access to read the content directly.

It works with a prefix `/var/task/`