# Best approach for using Lambda Layers to store certificates

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ca, aws-lambda-layers

We are using AWS Gateway combined with a Lambda Authorizer. A Lambda Layer has been added to the Lambda Authorizer and is being used to share certificates across multiple Lambda functions. The certificates are stored and should be retrieved from AWS Secrets Manager.

When a certificate is updated we obviously need to ensure the Layer contains the updated certificates. I have read there is no way to force a cold restart of a Lambda without updating configuration or deploying a new version.

My question is around the best approach for creating a deploying a Layer to meet the above need.

Two possible approaches come to mind:

1. Creating a Layer that when it runs, retrieves the certificates from Secrets Manager and writing these to a directory
2. Have the secrets retrieved from Secrets Manager at build time, deploying only the required certificates with Layer

Note: The certificates and directory must be referenced in the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS env variable

Open to hearing other recommendations in the case I'm not on the right track.

Comment: What are the certificates used for?  Is the lambda validating/encrypting or signing/decrypting?

Comment: It is a public certificate and required for TLS connectivity, if that answers your question?

Comment: If the lambda only requires the public key, then there should be no requirement to keep that key secret.  A custom certificate validator could rely upon DynamoDB or similar to ensure it is always up to date. Separately, PKI is designed to have to avoid frequent updates to trust lists through CA’s and CRL’s. Why is the cert changing so frequently? Can it be signed by a less volatile CA?

Comment: The certificate will not change frequently at all. I am only thinking ahead to manage a process for when it does change. Considering the two options for the Layer, would one option be better for any reason?

Comment: Presumably you will also be updating functionality of these layers, runtimes, and other system wide changes on a more regular basis than replacing your PKI.  Every system is different, so it is impossible to give a perfect answer, but I would file this under YAGNI.  These sorts of sweeping updates are well addressed by systems like Pulumi, Serverless, and Terraform. To a certain extent, using layers complicates the update over an include/configuration entry in the IAC tool.

Comment: S3, SecretsManager, DynamoDB are all better options for storing this, than in a custom Lambda Layer. And also easier to update when needed. EFS would also work, but is more difficult to update.

Comment: Your use case is not clear. API Gateway offers TLS termination. From APIgateway on wards there is no need to have data encrypted in the backend, why would you want data passed between lambdas to be encrypted? depends on the use case but Important to say that when you want to have 1 lambda invoking another lambda data usually never leave the backend - and even if it leaves the backend - most http libraries nowadays supports TLS out of the box - and encryption will take place (again where api gateway is the TLS terminator) so I have a feeling that you are doing something wrong!

Comment: @MarkB, the cert is stored in secrets manager. This is more about how it can then be used in a Lambda

Comment: @Mercury, it’s for communication from a Lambda to Vault, which needs to be over TLS

Comment: @Mitch, thanks. I will look into the capabilities of Terraform a little more to see what can be done there. But agree, it could be I’m overthinking what is actually going to be needed

Comment: For what it’s worth, this was the approach taken for passing extra certs to a Lambda https://stackoverflow.com/a/63911162/4081730

Comment: If they're already in Secrets Manager, just have your Lambda function pull the cert down from Secrets Manager when the function is initialized.

Comment: @bmd that approach you linked to is only appropriate when the certs absolutely have to be in a specific folder other than `/tmp`. For your use case, I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: Appreciate the time, @MarkB. I'll look at going ahead with retrieving the secrets on initialisation and test this solution out. Feel free to add this as a solution and I will vote it up